# Discrepancy in marshal behaviour

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I am testing MOXy 2.5.0 RC1.

I marshalled the following to a string:

```
  <c r="C3"  xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
    <v>20</v>
  </c>
```

It is represented by https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/xlsx4j/java/org/xlsx4j/sml/Cell.java

Notice the absence of any @XmlRootElement annotation

With the reference implementation, the result, as expected, is:

```
javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "org.xlsx4j.sml.Cell" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation]
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:317)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:243)
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:96)
        at org.docx4j.XmlUtils.marshaltoString(XmlUtils.java:507)
```

With MOXy, the result is:

```
 <v>20</v>
```

Is this a known issue?  I haven't tried 2.4.2 RC1.

thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a known difference between [**EclipseLink MOXy**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) and the RI. We have left this door open in MOXy for the use case where you are marshalling into an `OutputStream` or `Writer` where the root element has already been written.

Are you counting on an exception being thrown.  When there is no root element you can wrap the object in an instance of `JAXBElement`.

**Workaround**

You can use a `JAXBIntrospector` to determine if an object has a root element.

```java
JAXBIntrospector introspector = jaxbContext.createJAXBIntrospector();
QName rootElement = introspector.getElementName(aPOJO);
if(null == rootElement) {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'll ponder the implications.  For the moment, it was more a surprise than anything ... if <c> contained 2 <v> children and user is Marshalling to a DOM Node, what happens then?