# Strange "missing an @XmlRootElement annotation" error, only with Maven, works in Eclipse

Tags: xml, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I wrote code that marshals xml data. Before marshaling the data to output i validate the data the way Blaise Doughan suggests [here](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/validate-jaxb-object-model-with-xml.html)

Running a simple test in eclipse (marshaling data an validating it) works fine, but as soon i run the test in console (mvn test) i get "missing an @XmlRootElement annotation".

The code is generated by moxy - without this annotation. And my Question is why it works in Eclipse? Or how to get it working also in console? The only explanation i have is that some dependencies are different (probably eclipse uses some internal xml stuff?)

I am aware of the possibility to wrap my root-element in JAXBElement - but for some reason it works in eclipse without annotation and without wrapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blaise is right, the jaxb.properties must be under resource in same folder structure(package) as in src/main/java folders.
In my case i have 20 of those files (and jaxb-classes for 20 xsd). To get it working without manually copying add to pom:

```
<build>
...
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/jaxb.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
...
</build>
```

the first "resource" adds the normal resource folder. the 2nd adds src/main/java but includes only all jaxb.properties wherever they are.

Answer (score 1):

[**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) will marshal without an `@XmlRootElement` annotation, the the JAXB reference implementation will complain.

- [Discrepancy in marshal behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16379488/discrepancy-in-marshal-behaviour/16379663#16379663)

I suspect that you do not have the `jaxb.properties` file in the correct location of your Maven setup.  If your domain model is in the `com.example.foo` package then the `jaxb.properties` file should go in the following location.

```
src/main/resources/com/example/foo/jaxb.properties
```

For an example project see:

- https://github.com/bdoughan/blog20110322

**UPDATE**

> is it possible to tell moxy/the marshaller to use a fixed
>   jaxb.properties and not to search it deep in package folders (i have
>   many of the and all are identical)

If you want MOXy to always be used as the JAXB (JSR-222) provider then you can add the following to your classpath:

```
META-INF/services/javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext
```

The `javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext` file will contain the following contents:

```
org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

Otherwise you can always use the native MOXy APIs to create the JAXBContext:

```java
    JAXBContext jc = org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(new Class[] {Foo.class}, null);
```

Comment: thx for fast reply, but how does this explain the difference between maven and eclipse? jaxb.properties were generated together with the domainclasses. the are in same package as "<rootelement>Type" and "ObjectFactory"

Comment: @dermoritz - For Maven you will need to move the `jaxb.properties` file under the `resources` folder.

Comment: now generated jaxb.properties is in src/main/resources - no change

Comment: @dermoritz - Did you give my GitHub example a try?  It is setup to use Maven.

Comment: ok, yesterday short before going home i obviously did not read correctly. it is working as soon as recreating the complete folders in resources. In my case i have to marshal 10 formats and the path are very deep. i'll will try to configure maven to accept the files within java directory. i'll come back if i hav the solution. or "accept" your solution.

Comment: is it possible to tell moxy/the marshaller to use a fixed jaxb.properties and not to search it deep in package folders (i hav many of the and all are identical)